# Forced POS Tagging using French Stanford POS Tagger

Tags: pos-tagger

I want to impose forced POS tagging of particular words in a French sentence.
How can I do that through code?

In the code below, I want to force tag précédent as Verb, but I am not able to do so.

Example:

```
String input = "Le jour précédent/VB";
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("french.tagger");
List<List<HasWord>> sentences = MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(newStringReader(input));
for (List<HasWord> sentence : sentences) {
    List<TaggedWord> tSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
}
```

Comment: First of all, format your code as a code block. It would be easier to read it.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, I don't have 50 reputation for comment!) It seems easier to do with [RDRPOSTagger](http://rdrpostagger.sourceforge.net/). RDRPOSTagger also supports pre-trained models for French POS and morphological tagging.